# A scar in the fabric of space and time - a true story

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, geography

A few days ago, Leonard was invited to attend a ceremony held in the principality of Monaco, to celebrate the birth of a new member of the sovereign family. Now standing in the middle of a busy airport hall, blinking as his eyes scan the departures board, he suddenly finds himself stunned, in disbelief.
He had explored the different options to get there and eventually booked a flight to Nice (France), an hour and twenty five minutes long, followed by a 6 minute helicopter flight - because *that's* how you go and meet the prince of Monaco. Yet, on the departures board right now is displayed a direct flight to Monaco - an option that he had not found to be possible - taking just ten minutes short of *two* hours.

> In what airport does Leonard find himself right now?

Comment: are the times correct?  1:25 + 0:06  as opposed to 1:50?  the difference doesn't seem that drastic rot13(naq pbhyq cbffvoyl or rkcynvarq ol n fznyyre, yrff cbjreshy cynar)

Comment: @SteveV Yes they are - it's a small scar. The difference cannot possibly come from what you say.

Comment: Maybe a [tag:geography] tag?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Done. Maybe now that the answer was found I could add a rot13(ynathntr) tag as well?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Probably best not to add such a big hint to the question after it's solved. Let it stand in the way that it was found and solved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think Leonard finds himself in:

> Naples, Italy.

Because:

> A 1:25 flight to the French city of Nice.
>  It is also a +/- 2 hours flight away from Munich, Germany.
>  The Italian name of Munich is Monaco. And since he is in an Italian airport, the Italian name is displayed.

On the suggestion in the comments:

> The difference in travel times cannot be explained by a slightly different flight path, different plane, etc. because Monaco doesn't have an airport.
>
>  I hope Leonard stuck with his original plan to go to Nice first, or he would have had a nasty surprise...
>  This reminds me of a recent news story of a guy Travelling to Rotherham, UK and ending up in Rotterdam, Netherlands [link](https://nltimes.nl/2019/08/29/slovakian-traveler-ends-rotterdam-instead-rotherham)

Comment: That's it! Green tick on its way. Perhaps you could also explain why @SteveV 's idea in the comment above couldn't possibly be right?

Comment: After edit: excellent answer, nailed it!